# Bibliography in LaTeX coding

Tags: bibliographies

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{databasebr.bib}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{databasebr.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}



In this paper, I try to extend the paper named "Frustration and Anger in Games" of Pierpaolo Battigalli, Martin Dufwenberg and Alec Smith\cite{battigalli}








\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I wrote the `databasebr.bib` as

```
@article{battigalli,
        title={Battigalli, P., A. Di Tillio, and D. Samet},
        author={Strategies and Interactive
        Beliefs in Dynamic Games},
        journal={Advances in
        Economics and Econometrics: Theory and Applications, Tenth World Congress},
        volume={1},
        pages={391-422},
        year={2013},
        publisher={Cambridge: Cambridge
        University Press},
    }
```

Still bibliography is not showing in the PDF. Can somebody tell me the mistake please? Thank you

Comment: Two things to fix first: 1. You are calling biblatex.sty twice. 2. Because you are using biblatex, you don't need `\bibliography{databasebr.bib}`. That's for bibtex.

Comment: In any case `\bibliography{databasebr.bib}` is the wrong syntax. The file name in `\bibliography` should be given without file extension: **`\bibliography{databasebr}`** would be correct. But you already have `\addbibresource{databasebr.bib}` (where you correctly include the extension). Remove the `\bibliography{databasebr.bib}` and load `biblatex` only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your code and two errors in your bib entry.

Please correct in your bib entry the line

```
  title={Battigalli, P., A. Di Tillio, and D. Samet},
```

to

```
  title={Battigalli, P. and A. Di Tillio and D. Samet},
```

Please see that I corrected the wrong first comma to correct word `and` and deleted the second wrong comma after `Tillio` ...

In your `tex` code you called `biblatex` twice with the effect that the first call and used option is ignored. BibLaTeX uses `\addbibresource` instead `\bibliography` ... You called `geometry` and `amsmath` twice too.

Please see the following MWE with included bibliography with package `filecontents`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{battigalli,
  title={Battigalli, P. and A. Di Tillio, and D. Samet},
  author={Strategies and Interactive
          Beliefs in Dynamic Games},
  journal={Advances in
           Economics and Econometrics: Theory and Applications, 
           Tenth World Congress},
  volume={1},
  pages={391-422},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Cambridge: Cambridge University Press},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in,showframe]{geometry} % <=======================
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{nccmath} % <================================================
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % <=================
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % databasebr.bib
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}


\begin{document}
In this paper, I try to extend the paper named "Frustration and Anger in 
Games" of Pierpaolo Battigalli, Martin Dufwenberg and 
Alec Smith\cite{battigalli}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and see its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Yes, okay, Thanks a lot!

Comment: The last comma in `title={Battigalli, P. and A. Di Tillio, and D. Samet},` still looks wrong. It should quite probably be `title={Battigalli, P. and A. Di Tillio and D. Samet},`

Comment: `publisher={Cambridge: Cambridge University Press},` should ideally be split into `publisher = {Cambridge University Press}, location = {Cambridge},`. **But** since this is an `@article` at the moment this will not be shown anyway. From what I can see this entry should actually be an `@inproceedings`. (cf https://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/economics/economics-general-interest/advances-economics-and-econometrics-tenth-world-congress-volume-1)

Comment: A full entry with all the available data is at https://gist.github.com/moewew/05baad0565ef4ff039025123fc8f2b00, but one may or may not want to include everything I listed there.

Comment: @moewe I added the last comma error to the answer, thanks.

Comment: @HENAM You are welcome!